# Use data from graphql response in React

Tags: reactjs, json, graphql

I guess this is a simple issue, but I am stuck here for a while, so any advice may be helpful!

I have a react app and I am calling a GraphQL api (with apollo). Inside an arrow function component I have:

```
const [executeQuery, { data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_ALL_TASKS);

const findId = (step) => {
    executeQuery({
      variables: {
        "query": {
          "state": "CREATED",
          "taskDefinitionId": "something"
      }
     }
    })
  }
```

The query is successful and in the browser inspect panel I get this as the graphql response:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "tasks" : [ {
      "id" : "2251",
      "name" : "some_name",
      "__typename" : "Task"
    } ]
  }
}
```

In my code I want to use the retrieved **id**. How can I isolate the id from the response? When I am trying to access the *data* I get an *undefined* error.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have the same problem, I realized it is a caching error happening in apollo client. I couldn't figure out the solution. However, I temporarily solved it by **downgrading the apollo client dependency to version 3.2.5**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are wrapping your `executeQuery` in a function.

The data will be part of the response so you can get it like this:

```js
const {data, loading} = executeQuery({
  variables: {
    "query": {
       "state": "CREATED",
       "taskDefinitionId": "something"
     }
   }
})

// may also need to check for the error state
if(loading){
  console.log("Loading...")
}else{
  /// the ids seem to be an array of objects
  const ids = data.tasks.map((task)=> task.id)
  console.log(ids)
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried to do also, but I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tasks') at Object.findId" 
Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @konkouts I updated the answer you basically need to check for both the loading and error states to see if the data has been returned correctly

Comment: From my tests it doesn't seem to be a loading situation. From a further research I figured it may has something to do with the apollo caching, but I am still trying to understand this.